# Date need to be converted in Specific format - AngularJs

Tags: mysql, angularjs, date, time

I am a newbie in angular. Here I am stucked at:

I want to use the DB date and time to convert into two specified formats -

All the data is coming from my DB mysql-

1. The age how much time ,day before the field is created  Example:(2d 3h 30min)
2. Convert the DB yyyy-MM-dd HH:ii:ss format to the dd-MM-yy Example:(02-03-14)

But as per my understanding date format takes unix timestamp in angular

How to convert it in unix timestamp using angularjs.

So How can we solve the problem?

Comment: momentjs is a good resource for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time over this I have figured out the solution for my 2nd problem i.e.

> "Convert the DB yyyy-MM-dd HH:ii:ss format to the dd-MM-yy Example:(02-03-14)"
>   As :

```
app.filter('dateFormater', function() {
    return function(input, scope) {
    if (input!==null){
        //breaks DB date to array
        var parts = input.split(/[-]/).filter(function(str){ return str !== '';});
        //Takes date with time and returns array with date at 0th position
        var date = parts[2].split(/[ ]/).filter(function(str){ return str !== '';});
    }
    var finalDate = date[0]+'-'+parts[1]+'-'+parts[0];
    return finalDate;
    };
});
```

Output will be in the format as specified in question i.e. 02-03-14 for date coming from database as 2014-03-02

Comment: Check whether the value is available or not before split as it may be the case

Answer (score 0):

you need to use date filter. read more about it on [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

you can use it like

```
<span> {{ date_expression | date : format}} <span>
<span> {{ 20140101 | date : 'dd-MM-yy'}} <span>
```

Comment: As I have mentioned the date is coming in yyyy-MM-dd HH:ii:ss format

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this library: http://momentjs.com